# PHP send form data not using ajax/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript

How would I go about submitting form data without using HTML forms.

I only need to send 1 input to example.php, and would like stay away from ajax/jQuery.

Also is it possible to send it in the background without redirecting/refreshing the page.

The code below is as far as I have gotten. I would like it to send `input_1` and it's value `value 1`
once the page loads to `example.php` without the page redirecting.

```
theForm = document.createElement('form');
theForm.action = 'example.php';
theForm.method = 'post';
newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
newInput1.type = 'hidden';
newInput1.name = 'input_1';
newInput1.value = 'value 1';
```

Comment: devices that support JavaScript but does not support AJAX ? AJAX is mainly JavaScript!

Comment: @ShivanRaptor im sorry need to fix that, there real buggy using jQuery so I rather just leave it to javascript

Comment: with out redirecting to example.php you can not. You should try if the devices support ajax through simple xhr request. Look up cross browser xhr.

Comment: There is a wide selection of devices which support jQuery today. What kind of devices are you using?

Comment: @Prasanth first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638984/send-post-data-to-php-without-using-an-html-form says it can be done but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: you need to do theForm.submit() at the end. But it will refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I think Jquery works fine with the devices which supports Javascript.
However you can stick to the traditional xmlhttprequest.
check out the tutorial.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp