# How to send a Javascript Array and Form Input to PHP File (via $_GET for example)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Let's say I have a basic form like:

```
<form enctype="text/plain" id="form" action="results.php" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="option1">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="option2">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="option3">
</form>
```

and a Global Javascript Array "arr" in the same File and obviously want to send them both to the results.php via GET or POST in order to use them with some php functions. Is there a simple way to achieve this, using only basic Javascript, HTML and PHP? (Well JQuery aswell I guess)

Thanks for your input :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send POST data to PHP without using an HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638984/send-post-data-to-php-without-using-an-html-form)

Comment: $.ajax with jQuery should do the job.  You can try running the following: $.ajax({url: "file.php", data: data: $(this).serialize(), success: function(json) {});

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to encode the array using JSON, and then add it to the serialized form.

```
$.post("script.php", $("#form").serialize + '&arr=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr)), function(response) {
    ...
});
```

In PHP you would then decode the JSON:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['arr']);
```