# How do I integrate google sign in to my website and collect the users details?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-signin

I want to integrate the google sign in button onto [my website](https://shillax.win). I know html but I am unsure on php and java script. Ultimately, I would like the google sign in to sign in the user and give me their information so i can store it on my database on phpmyadmin securely. I have visited [the google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) for this but found it did not explain how to collect the users information fully. I have attempted to follow this and so far I have [this](https://shillax.win/testnoob/) but it is far from what it should be like. I have watched other tutorials such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hazMyK_cnzk&feature=youtu.be&t=1). However i find they all do not follow the googles instructions as for example you have to download a google API in them, however on the google website it does not mention downloading anything.

Below is the code of [what i have managed to do so far](https://shillax.win/testnoob/) by using the google tutorial:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="808271051181-424qcdq0emrd0pd77frfiuacvcetp58t.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get all data from the profile in javascript, but I wanted to get all their data into php variables so that I could store in my database.  To do this I sent the google id token as post data from javascript (how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638984/send-post-data-to-php-without-using-an-html-form)).
You still need all the other google sign in code you have, but I replaced `onSingIn` with this:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    document.getElementById("userid").value = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    document.getElementById("userid").form.submit();
}
```

Also add the form code in the body:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="userid">
</form>
```

You then need another file I called it login.php which contains the following function:

```
function get_var($var)
{
    $id = $_POST["id"]; // id from google
    $id_token = file("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" . $id); // decrypted id
    foreach ($id_token as $part) {
        // part is a factor of the user such as name or email
        // remove unecessary charcters
        $peice = str_replace("\"", "", $part);
        $peice = str_replace(",", "", $peice);
        $peice = substr($peice, 0, strpos($peice, ":") + 2);
        if (strpos($peice, $var) !== false) {
            $var = str_replace("\"", "", $part);
            $var = str_replace(",", "", $var);
            $var = substr($var, strpos($var, ":") + 2);
            return $var;
        }
    }
}
```

With this you should be able to get all the information you need.  Example uses:

```
$name = trim(get_var("name"));
$email = trim(get_var("email"));
```

To view all the accessible information either print out `$id_token` in `get_var` or go to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token= adding an id token at the end.
More information about getting data from an ID token [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).