# How to get php session data from a google sign in

Tags: php, session-variables, google-signin, session-state, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a website where users login with their google login (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).  The site has multiple pages and gets data for the user from a mysql database.  I would like to store the users' data (name, email) in a php session to have ready for the php when accessing the database.  The login function works, but I can't figure out how to get the data to php, with it currently all in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't a conventional way to do this, but I was able to get the information from the google auth token

```
function get_var($var_index) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $id_token = file("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" . $id);
    $var = str_replace("\"", "", $id_token[$var_index]);
    $var = str_replace(",", "", $var);
    $var = substr($var, strpos($var, ":") + 2 );
    return $var;
}


$name = get_var(12);
$email = get_var(5);
$img_url = get_var(13);
$exp = get_var(8);
$iss = get_var(9);



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] < $exp) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["name"] = $name;
    //$_SESSION["imageurl"] = $img_url;
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["exp"] = $exp; // when to auto logout

     header("LOCATION: page.php");
     exit();
} else{
    header("LOCATION: loginpage.html");
}
```

Comment: Updated version of this function and more information on how to implement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56990951/7690862)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for this. It's a very efficient way. just make sure you have jquery uncmopressed or minified (not slim) in you page and you're good to go.

This my javascript code in my page where the button is:-

```
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {

        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "googlesignin.php?action=google",
            data: "gmail=" + profile.getEmail() + "&name=" + profile.getName(),
            success: function(result) {

                if (result == 1) {

                    alert("Hello, " + profile.getName());

                    $("#googlesignin").hide();

                } else {

                    alert("failed to login");

                }
                
            }
            
        })

    }
```

So now the new file called googlesignin.php from where you will execute the insert query to the mysql database

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "google") {

$email = $_POST['gmail'];

$name = $_POST['name'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM google WHERE email='".$email."' AND name='".$name."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    echo 1;
    
} else {

    $query = "INSERT INTO google (email, name) VALUES ('".$email."', '".$name."')";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    echo 1;
    
}
```

}

so now we have stored our post variables as php variables and we can use them easily to execute our insert query. but we need to check whether the email has first registered or not.